# finding minimum of a subarray while the value might be only 1 or 2 or 3

Tags: c, arrays

[I have a problem](http://justpaste.it/exc4) with the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
  {
  int len,no,n,a,result;
  int start[100],end[100];
  int width[100];

  printf("enter the lenghth of the road : \n");
  scanf("%d",&len);

  printf("enter the width of the road ,in unitwise format for the given length : \n");
  for(n=0;n<len;n++)
    scanf("%d",&width[n]);

  printf("enter the no of testcases : \n");
  scanf("%d",&no);

  printf("for each testcase enter the starting and  end point : \n");
  for(n=1;n<=no;n++){
    printf("for testcase %d enter the start and end point respectively",n);
    scanf("%d %d",&start[n],&end[n]);}

    for(n=1;n<=no;n++){
        for(a=start[n];a<=end[n];a++){
        result=3;
        if(width[a]<result)
          result=width[a];
        }

      printf("for testcase %d the vehicle that can be used is %d",n,result);
      printf("\n");}
    }
```

I am not getting the right result although I feel I have applied right logic in finding minimum width. What is wrong with this logic?

Comment: Post the problem **here**. Clicking on the link doesn't get us any further as you need to sign up before.

Comment: What is the "right" rwesult ? What is this the expected output for what input ?

Comment: here is the complete problem     http://justpaste.it/exc4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line

```
result=3;
```

before your loop.

Comment: yea..such a silly mistake.thanks   PS: any better solution with arrays only(as in without advanced data structure like queues/stacks etc)